# How do i filter with time only Google Sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, time

I'm trying to filter out a set of data within a specific hour here's my formula:

Column D is the actual day and D is the time of the day (Column C)
=QUERY('RD'!A3:W,"SELECT F,H,O,Q WHERE G = '"&$F$3&"' AND C = Date '"&TEXT($C$35,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND (D >= TIME '"&TEXT(F35,"HH:mm:ss")&"' AND D < TIME '"&TEXT(G35,"HH:mm:ss")&"')")

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFLjH.png)
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgXm3.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Found one working with importrange and cell reference here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124809/google-sheets-query-with-date-and-time With Demo here: https://i.imgur.com/N82AZG0.gif 2nd Example: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88774/query-or-filter-the-data-where-the-start-time-is-past-300-pm

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY('RD'!A3:W,
 "select F,H,O,Q 
  where G = '"&$F$3&"' 
    and C = date '"&TEXT($C$35, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and D >= timeofday '"&TEXT(F35, "HH:mm:ss")&"' 
    and D <  timeofday '"&TEXT(G35, "HH:mm:ss")&"'")
```

see: **https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage**

Comment: i attached screenshots, i tried what you sent but it doesnt seem to be working, getting this error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Invalid date literal [2021-06-01 AND D >= timeofday ]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd.